# How to check record in specific date exist or not in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
where trunc(ci.dat_creation) 
between '01-may-2015' and '31-jul-2015' 
and  hbl.TRANS_DATE > '1-jun-2015'
```

this is my query where clause ci.datcreation tells get customer those register between may to jul and get records of those customers which have done their first transaction in july now hbl.dat_creation get records of transaction above june i want my query check transaction date should be june and transaction not exist before june how can i acheive this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ci.dat_creation and hbl.trans_date are of DATE or TIMESTAMP datatype, you should explicitly convert your dates-as-strings into dates, eg:

```
where  trunc(ci.dat_creation) between to_date('01/05/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('31/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
and    hbl.TRANS_DATE > to_date('01/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Also, bearing in mind that DATEs and TIMESTAMPs contain the time as well, if you're expecting your filter results to include rows where the ci.dat_creation is at 1pm on 31st July, you'll need to amend your where clause to something like:

```
where  trunc(ci.dat_creation) >= to_date('01/05/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
and    trunc(ci.dat_creation) < to_date('31/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
and    hbl.TRANS_DATE > to_date('01/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

With regards to your question, here's an example of how I would do it (you'll have to amend as appropriate for your query, since you didn't see fit to include the whole of it!):

```
with sample_data as (select 1 id, to_date('01/08/2015 12:39:28', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
                     select 1 id, to_date('15/08/2015 23:31:42', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
                     select 1 id, to_date('17/08/2015 08:29:36', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
                     select 2 id, to_date('16/08/2015 10:43:17', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
                     select 2 id, to_date('17/08/2015 17:51:11', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual)
select id,
       dt
from   (select id,
               dt,
               count(case when dt < to_date('15/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') then 1 end) over (partition by id) num_dts_before
        from   sample_data)
where  dt >= to_date('15/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
and    num_dts_before = 0;

        ID DT                   
---------- ---------------------
         2 16/08/2015 10:43:17  
         2 17/08/2015 17:51:11
```

Obviously, in your code, you would paramaterise the date you're checking for (ie, in my query above, replace `to_date('15/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` with something like `p_date_check`).